# Stop an Excel macro, triggered by the value of another cell changing, from being fired multiple times,

Tags: excel, vba

My macro essentially copies the value in B2 down to the next empty cell in column B.

A clock on another sheet, at a specific time, triggers the macro for one second only.

I was using a copy and paste macro. At the exact second the trigger equaled the specified time, the macro fired multiple times, usually 4-6 times. I want only one copy of the cell.

I changed the way I copied the value but the same issue occurred. This is the code below;

```
Sub Macro5()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B6").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("B2")

End Sub
```

How do I stop my macro from copying the value in B2 multiple times in that one second?

**EDIT**

This is the code I used originally.

```
Sub Macro5()

Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B6").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    
End Sub
```

I used a copy and paste values function.

The macro was triggered, to work on Sheet1, by the value of another cell changing on Sheet2. That cell's value was the result of a formula so Sheet2 had to be a Calculate event worksheet.

Sheet2 doesn't have any event types on it, just macros running specified to run on Sheet2.

Comment: Is that other code a `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: no both codes were done on calculate worksheets. I think I could create a change event though if you had an idea how to fix the multi copying on that?

Comment: What is the other code? Can you [edit] your question with it?

Comment: yeah I'll try to find the old one to copy in

Comment: older code added, with a bit more detail on how it runs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in this macro rather the one calling it

```
Sub Macro5()
 dim time as date
 time = Now()
 'you can change time from 5 seconds to more or less
 time = (DateAdd("s", 5, time))
 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 Range("B6").Select
 Selection.End(xlDown).Select
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("B2")


' for 5 seconds do nothing
DoEvents
Do Until time < Now()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried this entered, and it initially works great just makes one copy at the specific second, then a few seconds pass and it repeats itself and then once more. Do you have any thoughts as to how to stop it multi copying over a few seconds?

Comment: As in maybe a way to get it to only run at that specific second and only once, thanks for the help so far

Comment: Friendly hint: in nearly every case it's better to [avoid Select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=SearchResults&s=1|198.5635) :-)

Comment: thanks for the link to read through, I had a look but can't understand what the use of Select might have on the reason why the code is repeating a few times?

Comment: so I followed the link you left and rewrote the code avoiding using Select but it still copies the cell multiple times

Comment: change 2 in DATEADD function to 50 or 100 its the amount of time this Subroutine or any other Subroutine will not be triggered. As i mentioned before the problem is not in this macro its in the other macro which is calling this one

Comment: abdullah thanks very much, it's definitely making progress - the date add function of the code, can you use that to outline how many seconds the code waits before it executes the function? So where you said you can change it to 5 seconds or whatever you want, is that 5 seconds it waits after the trigger has occurred before it functions the macro?

Comment: no no it execute the code and then wait for 5 second before it exist That part which is commented as wait for 5 second is looping the code  and doing nothing for 5 second

Comment: Is it possible to use that time delay to trigger another macro. By this I mean could you specify that you take Time Now() then add say 5 seconds then call the next macro which then waits 5 seconds and calls the next macro etc.

Comment: If you can use a 'Then Call' function within the code above, where would you place it? Could you place it under the Time=Date(Add.... line?